# newPendingTransactions returning old transactions

Tags: websocket

I'm building an application where i need to keep track on new pending transactions.
I'm somehow receiving old pending transactions, an example is this one
https://etherscan.io/tx/0x716544baa4987e72265c001ecd953dad8a36383b786a06211fe6ce86d80841c6

Which has been pending for 11 days. How does this come through the newPendingTransactions subscription?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The pending transaction pool is constantly changing. It is possible for a transaction to be dropped and to appear again several day later if it is valid.

When the gas price increases some transactions with low gas price are dropped, but when the gas price decreases those transaction can appear again.

Every participant node is constantly exchanging transactions and block with other nodes. If one node drop a transaction it doesn't mean every other node will drop it. If one node has it, it can be propagated to the other nodes.